# Problem with string compare in if statement

Tags: string, compare, tcl

I have got a problem with this string comparison script:

```
set result [string range "0002150C0E67" 8 11 ];
if {[expr {$result != "FFFF"  && $result != "0000"}]} {set result "OK byte 5&6 = 0x$result" } {set result "Fail Byte 5&6 = 0x$result" };
```

If I change "0002150C0E67" to "0002150C0D67" or "0002150C0F67" (or a lot of other combinations), I get an OK result.

What is wrong?

Comment: @glennjackman The trick is that `0E67` is a floating point number. More conventionally written `0.0`.

Comment: Yea, it would have been clearer if OP mentioned that `0E67` was the anomaly. At first glance, it seemed like the other two were the anomalous ones.

Comment: It wasn't until I _actually ran the code_ that I realised what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at your code:

```
set result [string range "0002150C0E67" 8 11 ]
```

At this point, `result` is set to the string `0E67`. That's a string that looks like a floating point number that evaluates to 0×10<sup>67</sup>, which is just zero.

Now, simplifying your conditional (the extra `expr` added nothing) and reformatting to follow conventional style (in a functionally equivalent way), we get this:

```
if {$result != "FFFF" && $result != "0000"} {
    set result "OK byte 5&6 = 0x$result" 
} else {
    set result "Fail Byte 5&6 = 0x$result" 
}
```

As we can see, the second not-equals comparison is not satisfied so the "Fail" path is chosen. Far better is to parse the string like this:

```
scan "0002150C0E67" "%8x%4x" -> result
```

Then we do *numeric* comparisons on result and `format` to produce output:

```
if {$result != 0xFFFF && $result != 0} {
    set result [format "OK byte 5&6 = 0x%04x" $result]
} else {
    set result [format "Fail Byte 5&6 = 0x%04x" $result]
}
```

Comment: An alternative would have been to change the `!=` operators to `ne` to force string comparisons, but this _really_ is about doing integer parsing so we should stick with that.

Comment: Hi Donal
Thank you very much. It works and now we can produce again :)